# How to allow a custom application with SELinux?

Tags: fedora, systemd, selinux

I have a Go application that has a basic systemd service that runs with the user `web`. NGiNX talks to it via reverse proxy, and it talks to the MySQL database on the same server. NGiNX and MySQL policies were easy enough to set up with SELinux, however, I cannot for the life of me get SELinux to work with my custom Go application.

I'm getting a permission denied error, however when I disable SELinux everything runs just fine, so I know for sure that it's SELinux.

**About the Application**

1. Opens port 8080
2. Talks to MySQL over port 3306

I have tried following [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/writing-a-custom-selinux-policy_using-selinux) guide by RedHat on how to configure a custom application, but for some reason my application always remains as `unconfined_t` after using the `sepolicy` script.

**Note**: This is on a Fedora 36 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved it. Simply needed to add my custom binary to the `bin_t` label. I used this command `semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "/path/to/binary"` then used `restorecon -v /path/to/binary`. Then a quick `systemctl restart mybinary.service` and it seems to work flawlessy.

I also, added the static content for my site under the `httpd_sys_content_t` using the same commands, then reloading NGiNX.